# Installing 64 bit Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit

I am using Dell vostro 1550 laptop. It has intel i3 2nd gen processor and 2gb RAM and running Windows 7 64 bit. Can I install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit on my laptop?

Comment: @karel I would run 64 bit ubuntu on all 64 bit CPU regardless of RAM. 64 bit does not use enough more RAM to make a difference in performance.

Comment: did u install 64? did it perform?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can!
You qualify the minimum specs requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is YES. Long Answer Is YES, but you will need to do googling on what hardware you have and what is supported on the 64bit system, and if you do not have a plan to add more RAM, i would suggest sticking with a 32BIT Distro.